# In Laravel 5, how do you dump variables on vue enabled templates?

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

Prior to vue being part of Laravel, I would often debug by simply using {{ dump($var) }}

Doing so now throws an exception within javascript as Vue doesn't like <script> tags within the body of the content. It's not game breaking, but it is annoying. It still shows the whole array, just that the JavaScript around it doesn't work anymore.

Is there a Vue equivalent of laravel's dump? Can I tell Vue to ignore script tags when doing debugging?

To be clear, I'm looking to output the variable from PHP where it shows the properties, attributes, the type of value etc. I'm not looking to output an object within JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try {{ var_dump($variable) }}

If you are just looking to see the contents of the variables you are working with you can use the PHP functions var_dump() instead of dump(). It's not styled in the same sleek way that dump() is and you can't collapse or expand sections like you can with dump(). But it will dump the data you need without messing with your Vue code.

{{ dump($variable) }} without Vue:
[image: dump image]

{{ var_dump($variable) }} with or without Vue:
[image: var_dump image]

Comment: vue prints TypeError: "_vm.var_dump is not a function"

Comment: its print razor or twig build in template processor !

Answer (score 2):

console.log() will work but it will work only via javascript but i personally suggest that you will use vue.js plugin from browser? its way better to understand what is really happening on your vue variables in the back.

heres the link for

[vue dev tools chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)

then on your browser(F12) u will find it from Vue tab together console,network html.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm looking to view the variable from PHP. Vue is breaking whatever Laravel outputs when using the dump function. So at this point, the variables doesn't exist in Vue. I can move the div that contains the vue app to after where the dump is used, but that will cause the vue components not to work. I am hoping there is or will be a debug option to have Vue ignore that restriction on script and style tags when I use laravel debugging options.

Comment: if u want to view variable from php into vue components then use props.. 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

if youre using vue 1. and in your blade template wrap your component props into 
<component :variable = "{{ json_encode($ur_data) }}"></component>

if vue2
you can direct it
<component :variable = "{{ $ur_data }}"></component>

and catch it in your template using 
props :['variable']

then u can see ur php variable via template

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have the dump() *outside* the div your vue app is mounted to. So for example in your layout.blade

```
<body>
    @yield('dump')
    <div id="app">
```

Then in your index.blade

```
@extends('layout')

@section('dump')
@dump($variable)
@endsection
```