# VS Code - Debugging VUE component in Laravel project - Unverified breakpoint

Tags: debugging, laravel-5, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a VUE component in Laravel 5.5 project using VS Code.

The last version of VS Code is installed.
Debugger for Chrome 4.2.0 is installed.
All Chrome processes are killed.

launch.json in .vscode folder has the following code:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ]
    },  
]
```

I start the project from CMD like this:

```
λ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

I set a breakpoint in Vue component and start debugging
[(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1kMp.png)

As the result, the project page is opened in Chrome, but breakpoint doesn't work.
It is greyed out with the following message:

```
Unverified breakpoint, Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found
(source map problem?)
```

I found 4 files with the name "webpack.mix.js" in the project folder. I have added the ".sourceMaps();" to each of them like this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps();
```

After that I rebuild the project by:

```
npm run dev
```

But I didn't find any map files in CSS folder and the problem is still here.

Comment: Are you using laravel-mix?

Comment: If you are, you'll probably need to enable source-maps.

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#working-with-stylesheets

Comment: I can see laravel-mix in package,json

Comment: Read the documentation and you'll understand what to do

Comment: source-maps are enabled in webpack.mix.js, but the problem is still here

Answer (score 5):

This is the configuration that worked for me, it allows me to set breakpoints for `.vue` and `.js` files directly in VSCode:

VSCode's `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "vuejs: chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///resources/assets/js/*.vue": "${workspaceFolder}/resources/assets/js/*.vue",
            "webpack:///./resources/assets/js/*.js": "${workspaceFolder}/resources/assets/js/*.js",
            "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
        }
    }]
}
```

`webpack.mix.js`:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sourceMaps(false, 'source-map')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later.

Comment: Thanx! For those who didn't get it working, you might have to tweak the paths to reflect your setup for instance in my setup vue files were located at _resources/js_ instead of _resources/assets/js_

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately ".sourceMaps()" doesn't help, but the "debugger" keyword can be used instead of standard breakpoints in this case. You just have to add it to needed line of code and the code stops there.

[image: VSCode screenshot demonstrating use of debugger statement]

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same behavior. Debugger word in code works, but vscode red dot regular breakpoints doesn't.
I tried many fixes and combinations with *sourceMapOverrides* paths, but finally only set my `devtools` sourcemaps type to 
**`cheap-module-eval-sourcemap`** solve problem for my project!

In your *webpack.mix* try this line:

```
mix.webpackConfig({ devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-sourcemap' })
```

See my [github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/620#issuecomment-569506869) comment and issue to get more details

Maybe it would be good to try [all of that types](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool) if that does not working

Here is my debug config:

```
{
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///resources/js/*.vue": "${workspaceFolder}/resources/js/*.vue",
            "webpack:///./resources/js/*.js": "${workspaceFolder}/resources/js/*.js",
             "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
       },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use VueJS chrome dev tool extension from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd/related?hl=en)
as advised is this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183127/1565971)